# How to link to a local Haskell library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

There are current two projects with stack and cabal files each (I use stack to build), one is an exe called test and the other is a library called testlib. I want to use testlib in the test project, what can I do to let stack know testlib is a custom library and how to find it?

```
-- projects/test/test.yaml
-- projects/testlib/testlib.yaml
```

Comment: How often does the `testlib` change? I've struggled with this in the past and one easy way that doesn't pollute the `test`'s codebase is installing the `testlib`. Back when I used cabal, you could create a sandbox for such a project set and install everything there. Since stack has no package conflicts by definition, though, you might get away with just installing your package globally.

If you want to write code in both projects often, though, and see changes in respective builds, prepare to endure at least some of the annoyances of such setup.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer below. (So that I can't comment on why I don't like it ;) )

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thanks for reply;) The library I use not change much. Any better way to do? I have look throuth the stack configuration doc and only found this config item may be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I find the answer.

[extra-deps](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#packages-and-extra-deps) solve the problem.

And the test.yaml seems like:

```
...
extra_deps:
- ../testlib-1.0.0
...
```

Two points should be noticed:

1. the path should be relative to the directory containing test.yaml
2. the name of target lib should be like LIBNAME-VERINFO1.VERINFO2

---

Any better solution will be welcome. And thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extra-deps` or `packages` according to taste. `packages` should be used when the extra library (`testlib` in your example) is part of your development work, and `extra-deps` when you have a stable release.

The [manual](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/) has more details.